# looking for a 3D version of numpy.linalg.norm

Tags: python, performance, numpy, norm

I'm looking for a build-in function in python. It should compute the frobenius norm of a 3D array.
My current approach is:

```
    np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(x[:,:,:])))
```

but this is too slow for the size of my arrays.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.linalg.norm` will work fine on higher-dimensional arrays:

```
x = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
print np.allclose(np.linalg.norm(x), np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(x))))
# True
```

Comment: Great, it is described as a 1 or 2d function in the manual... Do you also now if there is a possibility to use nansum instead of sum? Would a masked array work?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? :-)